# Syntax error in sql create function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting the following error whenever i'm trying to create the following function in mysql.
error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

And my function is

```
    CREATE FUNCTION GET_HOUR_MINUTES(seconds INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(16)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(16);
    IF seconds >= 3600 THEN SET result = TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%kh %lm');
    ELSE SET result = TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%lm');
    RETURN result;
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter before creating a function. If you don't your CREATE statement terminates at the first semi-colon.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION GET_HOUR_MINUTES(seconds INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(16)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(16);
    IF seconds >= 3600 THEN SET result = TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%kh %lm');
    ELSE SET result = TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds),'%lm');
    END IF
    RETURN result;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks to @Ravinder for catching the missing END IF.

Comment: Add `END IF` before `RETURN` statement. And it should be working.